# How to make Leaflet-Search working when a layerGroup is switched-off by L.control.layers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am facing difficulties when using plugin **Leaflet.Control.Search** by Stefano Cudini together with Leaflet's built-in function **L.control.layers**.

As long as all layers are switched-on there are no issues at all in finding a location.

Once one of the layers is switched-off, then Leaflet-Search cannot find a location and while typing in searchbox following error message appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layerPointToLatLng' of null
at e.getBounds (leaflet.js:5)
at e._searchInLayer (leaflet-search.js:555)
at leaflet-search.js:594
at eachLayer (leaflet.js:5)
at e._searchInLayer (leaflet-search.js:593)
at leaflet-search.js:605
at eachLayer (leaflet.js:5)
at e._recordsFromLayer (leaflet-search.js:604)
at e._fillRecordsCache (leaflet-search.js:744)
at leaflet-search.js:706
```

If you turn on again the hidden layer then search functionallity is back to normal operation.

I created a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wilopey/4/edit?js,console,output) showing the issue, although you cannot see specifics about exact error, because it is showing just "script error". Try to search a site - the available names are 1000, 1100, 1110 and 1111. It will work. Then switch-off one of the layer groups from layer control and try again - it will show an error. Switch on again and will continue working normally.

I will appreciate if someone can give me a suggestion what I am doing wrong or what work-around can be implemented. Thank you in advance!

The code in short:

Sites are defined in two arrays:

```
var sites1 = [
{"loc":[51.582521, -0.118155],"Site":"1000"},
{"loc":[51.587454, -0.106052],"Site":"1100"}
];
```

Arrays are looped and added to a layer group:

```
var layerSites1 = L.layerGroup();

for(var i in sites1) {
var title = sites1[i].Site, 
loc = sites1[i].loc,        
marker = new L.circle(new L.latLng(loc),
       {radius: 100,title: title,color: 'red'})
       .bindPopup('Site: '+ title);

layerSites1.addLayer(marker);
}
```

The two layer groups are defined as overlays:

```
var overlays = {

    "Sites1": layerSites1,
    "Sites2": layerSites2
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlays).addTo(mymap);
```

Then they are added to a common layer group, which is used for searching in by Leaflet Search:

```
var layerAll = L.layerGroup([layerSites1,layerSites2]);
```

The definition of Leaflet Search is below:

```
var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
    position:'topright',        
    layer: layerAll,
    initial: false,
    hideMarkerOnCollapse: true,
    zoom: 17

});

mymap.addControl(controlSearch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the solution was rather easy. I just needed to add a **try-catch statement** in leaflet-search.js source code.

In the current plugin release **try** is to be added for _searchInLayer function on row 528. **catch** needs to be added on row 599 (originally row 598 before adding "try" on 528).

Like that even one of the layer groups part of the main layer group, in which searching is committed, is switched-off, there is no exception thrown, tooltip is shown and the searched location is shown and is highlighted.

The updated code now looks like following:

```
_searchInLayer: function(layer, retRecords, propName) {
try {
var self = this, loc;

if(layer instanceof L.Control.Search.Marker) return;

if(layer instanceof L.Marker || layer instanceof L.CircleMarker)
{
  if(self._getPath(layer.options,propName))
  {
    loc = layer.getLatLng();
    loc.layer = layer;
    retRecords[ self._getPath(layer.options,propName) ] = loc;
  }
  else if(self._getPath(layer.feature.properties,propName))
  {
    loc = layer.getLatLng();
    loc.layer = layer;
    retRecords[ self._getPath(layer.feature.properties,propName) ] = loc;
  }
  else {
    //throw new Error("propertyName '"+propName+"' not found in marker"); 
    console.warn("propertyName '"+propName+"' not found in marker"); 
  }
}
if(layer instanceof L.Path || layer instanceof L.Polyline || layer instanceof L.Polygon)
{
  if(self._getPath(layer.options,propName))
  {
    loc = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
    loc.layer = layer;
    retRecords[ self._getPath(layer.options,propName) ] = loc;
  }
  else if(self._getPath(layer.feature.properties,propName))
  {
    loc = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
    loc.layer = layer;
    retRecords[ self._getPath(layer.feature.properties,propName) ] = loc;
  }
  else {
    //throw new Error("propertyName '"+propName+"' not found in shape"); 
    console.warn("propertyName '"+propName+"' not found in shape"); 
  }
}
else if(layer.hasOwnProperty('feature'))//GeoJSON
{
  if(layer.feature.properties.hasOwnProperty(propName))
  {
    if(layer.getLatLng && typeof layer.getLatLng === 'function') {
      loc = layer.getLatLng();
      loc.layer = layer;            
      retRecords[ layer.feature.properties[propName] ] = loc;
    } else if(layer.getBounds && typeof layer.getBounds === 'function') {
      loc = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
      loc.layer = layer;            
      retRecords[ layer.feature.properties[propName] ] = loc;
    } else {
      console.warn("Unknown type of Layer");
    }
  }
  else {
    //throw new Error("propertyName '"+propName+"' not found in feature");
    console.warn("propertyName '"+propName+"' not found in feature"); 
  }
}
else if(layer instanceof L.LayerGroup)
{
  layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    self._searchInLayer(layer, retRecords, propName);
  });
}
  }
catch(err) {

}
},
```